# Bootstrap: Align nav in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a nav with Bootstrap v4 and I struggle because it does not work like I expect. The nav should consist of two navs overall, one at the left and one at the right. However, both are at the left.

As far as I understand the Bootstrap docs, this should work. But it does not. Where is my mistake?

I'm using the `justify-content-end` class, what should be fine, right?

[image: The second part of the nav should be on the right.]

```
<nav class="nav">

/* This should be on the left side */
<ul class="nav justify-content-start">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

/* This should be on the right side */
<ul class="nav justify-content-end">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
  </li>
</ul>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change from

```
<nav class="nav">
```

to

```
<nav class="navbar">
```